# How to fix: Failed to create component WindowsXamlHost. Could not find Windows Runtime type Microsoft.Tookit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.IXamIMetadataContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml-islands

I am trying to host UWP Controls on my .NET Framework 4.8 Application. After I have installed the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.XamlHost` Nuget Package, I added a WindowsXamlHost component to the form. However, this error message popped up:

[image]

I have looked on Github, but found no luck in solving this problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: From [WindowsXamlHostControl for Windows Forms and WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost): Important - Using the WindowsXamlHost control to host custom UWP controls is supported only in apps that target .NET Core 3. This scenario is not supported in apps that target the .NET Framework.

Comment: @mcalex You can host _standard_ UWP controls in WPF or WinForms using .NET Framework or .NET Core. (see: [Host a standard UWP control in a WPF app using XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands)
 
To host a _custom_ UWP control in WPF or WinForms, .NET Core 3 is required though. (see:[Host a custom UWP control in a WPF app using XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands)

Comment: Did you install [Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls)?

Comment: @mcalex Yes, I installed it

Comment: I also am getting this error. My application is .NET 4.7.2. and using VS v16.4.2.